# Colorboxes that break across pages

Tags: minipage, mdframed, comments

I am trying to build an environment/command that allows me to place comments in the text. The idea is to have  colored box that can break across pages and use the `\ttfamily` font with hyphenation. I also want to use any structure (table, enumerate, itemize, etc.) inside it. Moreover the box width is variable and the maximum is `\linewidth`. My MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{environ,varwidth}
\newsavebox\MyTempBox
\NewEnviron{mycomment}{%
\savebox\MyTempBox{%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\BODY
\end{varwidth}}%
\begin{mdframed}
[topline=false,
rightline=false,
bottomline=false,
leftline=false,
innerleftmargin=1ex,
innerrightmargin=1ex,
innertopmargin=1ex,
innerbottommargin=1ex,
backgroundcolor=pink,
font=\ttfamily,
userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd\MyTempBox\relax
]
\hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar\relax
\BODY
\end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{mycomment}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{mycomment}

\end{document}
```

So far it almost works, the problem is that it generates a lot of `Overfull \hbox` because the text does strictly not respect the box boundaries. If I put the second `\BODY` inside a minipage

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\BODY
\end{minipage}
```

It works better, but I loose the break over pages feature. I think that a minipage that can break over pages can be the solution.

I am not attached to the mdframed package. For example,

```
\newcommand{\ccomment}[1]{%
\noindent\colorbox{pink}{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth-1em}%
\ttfamily
\hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar\relax % enable hyphenation
#1
\end{varwidth}}}
```

Would be ok for me, but once more I cannot use it for long text that may break across pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply use `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{mycomment}
  {\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,
    rightline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    leftline=false,
    innerleftmargin=1ex,
    innerrightmargin=1ex,
    innertopmargin=1ex,
    innerbottommargin=1ex,
    backgroundcolor=pink,
    font=\ttfamily,
   ]\hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar\RaggedRight}
  {\end{mdframed}\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=-1 }

\begin{document}

\begin{mycomment}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{mycomment}

\end{document}
```

The final setting of `\hyphenchar` is to restore the default no hyphenation in the typewriter font (such assignments are always global).

---

For accommodating `varwidth` you have to supply the right line width; this of course needs the `environ` and `varwidth` packages.

```
\NewEnviron{mycomment}
  {\sbox0{\ttfamily\hbadness=10000
   \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex\relax}
   \BODY
   \end{varwidth}}%
   \begin{mdframed}[topline=false,
    rightline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    leftline=false,
    innerleftmargin=1ex,
    innerrightmargin=1ex,
    innertopmargin=1ex,
    innerbottommargin=1ex,
    backgroundcolor=pink,
    font=\ttfamily,
    userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+2ex\relax
   ]\hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar\RaggedRight\BODY
   \end{mdframed}\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=-1 }
```

With `\hbadness=10000` you turn off spurious `Underfull \hbox` messages.

Comment: I need an extra argument that tells me the width of the box, because sometimes the text does not have the text width, like I have in my MWE.

The use of `\RaggedRight` controls better the size of text, but it still gives me a lot of `Overfull \hbox` and if the text has less that text width I think it does not provide any result.

Comment: @cacamailg I've added a version with `varwidth`

Comment: I still see some `Overfull \hbox` but not as before. And you solution works well most of the time. Thanks!